# Are these combinations and permutations correct?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I wanted to know if I did these 3 questions correctly:

1. There are 100 distinct people in line. How many arrangements are there?
   Ans: Combination - 100!
2. There are 30 distinct objects. How many (unordered) selections of 6 objects can be obtained?
   Ans: Combination - (30, 6) = $$\frac{30!}{6!*24!}$$
3. How many different strings can be formed by reordering the letters of the phrase
   ’TYRANNOSAURUS REX’, counting the space?
   Ans: Permutation - $$\frac{17!}{3!2!2!2!2!}$$ because there are 3 R's and 2 A, N, S, and U's and the rest are 1's.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. It's for a sample exam and the professor did not post solutions.

Comment: In the first problem, you are counting (correctly) **permutations**, not combinations. All the expressions you obtained are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resulting expressions are all "spot on," *but* for problem $(1)$, we have a ***permutation*** of 100 folks, (and **not** a *combination*, though you do indeed have a combination in your second problem). Otherwise, it seems clear that you know what you're doing in each of these problems.